# Comparing one data structure against another resulting in run time of over 50 mins

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, spelling

I'm writing code which reads in a text file (each line a tweet) and goes through each tweet comparing it against a list of English words to see if the word is misspelled.

So the list of English words is read in from a text file as well, this is then stored in a List. When I run the code for this alone, it operates in less than one second. When I run the code for storing each word in the tweet file (without checking for spelling) for the 1,000,000 tweets, it stores each word and its frequency in a `HashMap<String, Integer>` in around 20-30sec.

But when I add the line to check if the word is spelled correctly, it causes a ridiculous run time increase, to the point where I could almost watch a movie before it finished running.

The simple aspect of invoking `isSpelledCorrectly(X)` (which just invokes `list.contains(x)`, which has a worst case run-time of O(n)), yet it seems quite confounding that it causes the code to go from a 30 sec runtime to a 50 min runtime?

Code:

Spelling:

```
static List<String> spellCheck = new ArrayList<String>();

public AssignTwo() throws IOException{
    spellCheck = initCorrectSpelling("C:\\Users\\Gregs\\InfoRetrieval\\src\\english-words");
}

public static List<String> initCorrectSpelling(String filename) throws IOException { //store correct spelling of words in list
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
    try{
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String next = scanner.nextLine();
            spellCheck.add(next);
        }
    }
    finally{
        scanner.close();
    }
    return spellCheck;
}

public static boolean isSpelledCorrectly(String word){  //check if any given word is spelled correctly by seeing if it is 
    boolean output = false;                             //contained within the spellCheck list
    if(spellCheck.contains(word)) output = true;                    
    return output;
}
```

Code storing Tweets:

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> misSpell;
public AssignOne() throws IOException {         //read in file from path, test functions
    index("C:\\Users\\Gregs\\InfoRetrieval\\src\\tweets");
}

public static void index(String filename)  throws IOException {
    misSpell = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
    try{
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();       
            String[] lineArr = line.split(" ");
            for(int i=3; i<lineArr.length; i++){
                int count=1;
                lineArr[i] = lineArr[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
                //if(!AssignTwo.isSpelledCorrectly(lineArr[i].toLowerCase())){  //with this line commented out, runtime <30sec, with line >50mins
                    if(misSpell.containsKey(lineArr[i].toLowerCase())){             
                        count = 1 + misSpell.get(lineArr[i].toLowerCase());             
                    }
                    misSpell.put(lineArr[i].toLowerCase(), count);
                //}
            }
        }
    } 
    finally{
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion on where to improve code or how to make the comparisons more efficient? Is there a faster data structure for correctly spelled words?

Comment: List.contains() is O(N), N being the number of words in the dictionary. Use a HashSet, where contains() is O(1). Using A buffered reader would also speed things up.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and give you an update on runtime

Comment: Calling toLowerCase() thrice on each word is also a time waster.

Comment: Thank you, this decreased runtime drastically, if you would like to leave it as an answer I will happily vote it best

Comment: I'd guess you are storing a lot of entries in both of your lists. The tweet-word-list and the dictionary-list. Thus this may be related to garbage collection (GC) issues. As your code has such a long runtime connecting against the running VM with JVisualVM should not be a problem. There you can inspect the memory and GC behaviour. If GC runs mad, it will consume all the CPU time trying to free some memory.

Comment: I know, but the problem is the tweets are an example of badly formed English, so there could be some words (As well as sentence starters) which have capitals, where the word wouldnt have a captial in the spelled correctly HashSet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.contains()` is O(N), N being the number of words in the dictionary.

Use a HashSet, where `contains()` is O(1).

Using A buffered reader would also speed things up. And avoiding to call toLowerCase() three times on each word would too.